# How to print only 3 digits of a reversed number in java( Let's say the number has 4 digits)

Tags: java, reverse

Let's say I have a number from user, for exemple: 456789.
I know how to print in reverse the number, but I am not sure how I can stop the execution to print only 3 first reversed digits. 
What I mean is that I want to print only 987 from the given number

I have to stop somehow with break; but I am not sure how.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number= 0;
    int numberInReverse = 0;
    System.out.println("Input a number");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    numar=sc.nextInt();

    while (number !=0){
        numberInReverse*=10;
        numberInReverse=numar%10;
        number/=10;
        System.out.print(numberInReverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: First reverse the string then use string.substring function to split the first three digits of the reversed string.   Numar =numar.reverse();  then numar.substring(0,3) will give you 987

Answer (score 3):

You could follow this algo:

1. modulo the number by 1000
2. reverse it
3. print

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert to into a StringBuilder and use `reverse()` and `substring()`:

```
String result = new StringBuilder()
        .append(numar)
        .reverse()
        .substring(0, 3);
System.out.print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Input a number");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int reversed = 0, counter = 0;

    while (counter++ < 3) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;
        num /= 10;

    }

    System.out.println("Reversed Number: " + reversed);
```

Comment: If you could explain what the code does and why you are comparing `counter++` to `3`, that would be awesome.  All-code answers/questions are not great.

Answer (score 0):

For the example of num = 456789
We have:
a) A quotient of 45678 when we do an Integer division, i.e. 456789 / 10
b) A remainder of 9 when we use the Modulus operator, i.e. 456789 % 10

If we update the 'new' number to be the quotient and by iterating,
the following table shows what it looks like:

```
digit number   quo   rem  Observations
----- ------ -----   ---  --------------------------------------------
  1   456789 45678    9
  2    45678  4567    8
  3     4567   456    7   STOP for 3 digits, i.e. number of iterations
  4      456    45    6
  5       45     4    5
  6        4     0    4   BREAK when variable 'quo' equals ZERO
```

For a first approach, consider calling the following method from your `main()`:

```
static void firstApproach(){
    int num= 456789;
    int quo= num / 10;
    int rem= num % 10;

    System.out.println( num + " | " + quo + " | " + rem );
}
```

This is the output we get:

```
456789 | 45678 | 9
```

Now, consider a second iteration by calling this method from `main()`:

```
static void secondIteration() {
    int num= 456789;
    int quo= num / 10;
    int rem= num % 10;
    System.out.println( num + " | " + quo + " | " + rem );

    num= quo;
    quo= num / 10;
    rem= num % 10;
    System.out.println( num + " | " + quo + " | " + rem );
}
```

Here's the output for two iterations:

```
456789 | 45678 | 9
 45678 |  4567 | 8
```

Carry on for yet a third iteration:

```
static void thirdIteration() {
        int num= 456789;
        int quo= num / 10;
        int rem= num % 10;
        System.out.println( num + " | " + quo + " | " + rem );

        num= quo;
        quo= num / 10;
        rem= num % 10;
        System.out.println( num + " | " + quo + " | " + rem );

        num= quo;
        quo= num / 10;
        rem= num % 10;
        System.out.println( num + " | " + quo + " | " + rem );

        // ... and so on ...
    }
```

And the output, after 3 iterations:

```
456789 | 45678 | 9
 45678 |  4567 | 8
  4567 |   456 | 7
```

Looking at the code for third iteration, observe the following repeating pattern that should go inside the body of a loop:

```
num= quo;
quo= num / 10;
rem= num % 10;
```

What if we try to specify some unreasonable amount of digits, say 10 for the same example of 456789?

This is why the loop needs two stoping conditions (whichever occurs first), namely:
- when it reaches the specified number of digits (3 in the example);
- when quotient gets to ZERO (hence the `break;`).

The following `reverse()` method shows a `while()` loop, where all variables are properly initialised to avoid any surprises. Tha variable `digit` is the one that controls the number of iterations for the loop and is incremented at the end:

```
static int reverse( int number, int numDigits ){
    int res= 0;
    int quo= number / 10;
    int rem= number % 10;

    int digit= 1;
    while( (digit <= numDigits) && (quo != 0) ){
        res= 10*res + rem;

        number= quo;
        quo= number / 10;
        rem= number % 10;

        digit= digit + 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

The above `reverse()` method can be called from `main()`:

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
    // firstApproach();
    // secondIteration();
    // thirdIteration();

    int result= reverse( 456789, 3 );  // reverses 456789, upto 3 digits
    System.out.println(  result );
}
```